# Continuity of inductively constructed lift to covering space

Tags: algebraic-topology, continuity, covering-spaces

I am following through the proof of lemma "(c)" of proposition 1.7 in Hatcher's AT, which says that if we have a covering space $\tilde X \xrightarrow{p} X$, an $F:Y \times I \rightarrow X$ and an "initial lift" $\tilde F_0: Y \times \{ 0 \} \rightarrow \tilde X$, then we can construct a (unique) lift $\tilde F$ of $F$ to $\tilde X$ which extends $\tilde F_0$.

I understand the inductive construction of $\tilde F$ around $\{ y_0 \} \times I$ for an $y_0 \in Y$. We find a neighborhood $N$ of $y_0$ and a partition of $I = [0,1]$, $0=t_0 < \ldots < t_m=1$, and an $\tilde F$ which is continuous on every $N \times [t_i, t_{i+1}]$, and their definitions agree on overlaps ($\tilde F|_{N \times [t_i, t_{i+1}]} := p_{\tilde{U_i}}^{-1}( F|_{N \times [t_i, t_{i+1}]} )$ for $U_i \simeq \tilde U_i$ through $p$ and $U_i$ a neighborhood of $F(N,[t_i,t_{i+1}])$).

What don't get is why $\tilde F$ constructed as such is continuous on $N \times I$. I'm thinking that if $Y$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space, then, since $N$ is open, we can find an open (precompact) neighborhood of $y_0$, say $M$, such that $\overline M \subseteq N$. Then $\tilde F|_{\overline{M} \times [t_i, t_{i+1}]}$ are all continuous too and we can apply the glueing lemma for the closed sets $\overline{M}\times [t_i, t_{i+1}]$, obtaining that $\tilde F|_{M \times I}$ is continuous, and this is fine because we only care about $\tilde F$ on a neighborhood of $\{ y_0 \} \times I$. But is $\tilde F_{N \times I}$ constructed as such continuous for an arbitrary $Y$?